# XCode 8.3.1 lost my files but I commit successfully to git ,someone else know it

Tags: xcode, git

one week ago,I commit a file to git using Xcode 8.3.1,but now,I create two branch,when I chekcout branchB ,then I checkout master, Xcode show me losing lot of files.everyone else know it .

Comment: `git reflog` may help.

Comment: I do it ,but log cannot Contain the file.

Comment: When you find a reflog that seems related with your lost commits, run `git log <reflog-commit>` to check its history. You may find the lost commits.

Comment: it show me detailinfo ,but not contain file I commit.when today,I just know the file I commit not existence。

Comment: Try `git log <reflog-commit> --name-only` to see if your file is included in some of the commits.

Comment: I tried. result is same.

Comment: Is is Xcode bug?

Comment: Try `git reflog | awk '{print $1}' | while read id;do echo $id;git ls-tree -r $id;done` to see if the file is in the output.

Comment: print los of files name ,but nor my losing file. Do you know reason about it?

Answer (score 0):

### just use mac soft named [**[Time Machine]**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ePoC.jpg) ;

```
1:open it, 
2:chose your want time and files recovery;
3: click  recovery[chose your Folder wanted  recovery];
4:done.
```